# Product List Issue

Tags: magento2, product-list, sorting, product-sorting

I'm having a problem with the product list in Magento 2. For the most part everything is working properly, but occasionally when I change the sort order to 'desc' or change the sort criteria to 'name' or 'price' the page breaks. It does not load all of the products that should be on the page and the page loses all javascript and css. I've included a screenshot of a page that is working in asc and breaks when flipped to desc.

[image: Working List]

[image: Not Working List]

Any suggestions on why this is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: When those action are performed, new page is loaded. Usually with extra query strings like `?product_list_order=price`. Could you watch the URL carefully? Does the domain change? Or, maybe the locale is changing (for which static files are not deployed)?

Comment: Hey @Marjan thanks for the response, the working url looks like : `https://magento.doublerdistributing.com/snow.html?p=21&product_list_dir=desc&product_list_limit=100&product_list_order=name`  and the non-working url looks like: `https://magento.doublerdistributing.com/snow.html?p=21&product_list_dir=asc&product_list_limit=100&product_list_order=name`

Comment: And if you try to "Inspect" with your browser. Are there any <link> tags inside <head> where you would notice changes in the "href" attribute?

Comment: @Marjan oddly enough the head tag is completely empty for the broken page, maybe this indicates a php error?

Comment: You are right I suppose. The content of the <head> is undoubtedly very important. But, all given so far, it is hard to say what goes wrong. Maybe bad layout instructions, or, a wrong override of some of the blocks. But, you need to find new clues at this point.

Comment: @Marjan I think you are right, I'll keep digging , thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of digging it seems that when calculating savings for products I was occasionally calling the PHP method getUsedProductIds() on a simple product. This was causing the issues and as soon as I put in a check to only run it on configurables it cleared. Silly me.